How to consolidate nested logarithms
I was playing around with logarithms and their properties and came across these little guys:
$$
\log_k{(\log_k{x})} \quad and \quad \log_k{(\log_j{x})}
$$
Is it possible to consolidate expressions of this type into a single logarithm without the logarithm being another logarithm?
I've tried using some properties like changing the base and manipulating powers, but all I found was this "identity" that only works when $x$ is a power of $j$ and $\log_j{(x)}$ is a power of $k$:
$$
\log_k{(\log_j{x})} = \log_{(j^k)}{x}
$$
Is there any known identity or transformation that I can apply to simplify these expressions? Any help would be very helpful!
Thanks! :)

If $x=j^{k^2}=(j^k)^k$, then $x$ is a power of $j$, $\log_j(x)=k^2$ is a power of $k$, and $\log_k{(\log_j(x}))=\log_k(k^2)=2$ but $\log_{j^k}(x)=k$. You might want to carefully review the derivation of your "identity."

There is no way to transform nested logarithms into a single logarithm.
The function $\log_a(\log_b(x))$ grows much more slowly than $\log_c(x)$, regardless of the bases $a$, $b$, and $c$. You can see this by exponentiating both sides with respect to $a$:
$$
a^{\log_a(\log_b(x))} = \log_b(x) \qquad a^{\log_c(x)} = c^{\log_c(a)\log_c(x)} = x^{\log_c(a)}
$$
But $\log_b(x)$ and $x^{\log_c(a)}$ cannot be equal for all $x$, since the former is a logarithm and the latter just is a power of $x$, so these are not the same thing.
